# How to avoid passing CancellationToken all over my dot net core code base?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a basic web app with dot net core and entity framework.
I was told to pass the cancellationToken all the way from the controller at the top to the entity framework at the bottom. My code looks kind of like this:

```
    public Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> GetAllUserAsync(string accountId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return _userService.GetAllUserAsync(accountId, cancellationToken);
    }
```

What should I do? I understand that if I remove cancellationToken then a canceled http request will not trigger a canceled db query.

Is there any way I can have the benefits of cancelation token but without the extra parameter polluting method signatures?

Comment: Do you actually have cases when you need to cancel database query? Feel free not to use it until you actually need it.

Comment: So basically if all my queries are short, I don't need it right? If I have a long running query triggered by a http request, I need to pass it like this.

Comment: Encapsulating it as a member of the enclosing class is the sensible alternative.

Comment: I think this is a design issue in the framework. Stuff like this should be part of the context object of the request.

Comment: Not everything has a request context. For instance a windows service. Having the token like that makes it easier to achieve graceful shutdown..

Comment: Even for long running queries (2-3 minutes), what happens if you will not cancel it?